# Wordpress / jquery menu scrolling

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, navigation

Im using Wordpress and i'm struggling with the menu heres the structure i have:

[image]

I have a problem i need to link the subcategories under Gallery to stay within the page of Gallery but simply scroll it down to the relevant area. I have no idea how i would achieve this. After trying to google search the answer for a while and getting nowhere i thought you fine people always after awesome suggestions.

I could possibly use jquery to move the menu but I'm also struggling on how to direct the subcategories back to the gallery page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using category menu, drag and drop the custom link menu and while expanding you will find a textbox to enter the href link.

There you can give the link of "Gallery page" by appending the id of particular div of the subcategory.

For exmple,

Gallery page URL - http://www.xxxxxx.com/gallery

Then give the subcategory link as - http://www.xxxxxx.com/gallery/#sub-category-content-div-id

So, in the same page the content can be located to respective subcategories.

Hope this helps you.